# Differences between Insights response time and App Service response time

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I noticed a difference in AVG and MAX response time between Insights (Performance / View in Logs / Response Time) and the response time that I see in the (Overview / Response Time) of the Web App.

The values on OverView are higher (seems that there are some requests that take 20 seconds and mess up the average.

I have no traces of these requests looking in the Insights response time or trying to search the requests that take more time.

Insights values seem more correct because seems that the web app is working properly. What could be that difference?

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question with yours: [What is the difference between Azure Monitor 'Response time' and AppInsights 'Duration'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858747/what-is-the-difference-between-azure-monitor-response-time-and-appinsights-du)

Response time in overview page is the Azure Monitor metric, just like the reply described:

> Azure Monitoring is gathering statistings on the web server as a
> whole. That's why it is reporting on CPU and memory usage in addition
> to response times.

Response time in performance is the Application Insights metric

> Application Insights calculate average request duration for all
> requests, without considering if calculated before request hits the
> load balancer.

Comment: Thank you I wasn't lucky with the search function...

Comment: Okay..would you mind accept my answer rather than vote? https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer